# GCP KMS:PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.viewPublicKey' denied on resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, public-key, google-cloud-kms

I'm working on a Java project and I have a need to fetch the encryption key from the GCP. Here is my code

```
`
public PublicKey fetchKey() {
  try  {
      KeyManagementServiceSettings keyManagementServiceSettings =
              KeyManagementServiceSettings.newBuilder()
                      .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
                              .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudkms"))))
                      .build();
      KeyManagementServiceClient client =
              KeyManagementServiceClient.create(keyManagementServiceSettings);

      // Build the key version name from the project, location, key ring, key,
    // and key version.
        CryptoKeyVersionName keyVersionName =
                CryptoKeyVersionName.of("khgvjgvhjyfjghb", "global", "test-key",
                        "test-key", "3");

    // Get the public key.
    PublicKey publicKey = client.getPublicKey(keyVersionName);
    //this.secretKey = publicKey.toByteArray();
    return publicKey;
  }catch (Exception e){
      throw new Exception(e);
  }
}
```

I keep getting this no permission error. And I have checked, my account does have the permission to access the key, and the GCP documentation does not have much to say about this

Please help
`Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.viewPublicKey' denied on resource`

I tried this code from the official gcp documentation and I expect the public key

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that you do not have the correct permission to specifically view the public key. https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/permissions-and-roles lists the roles which contain the viewPublicKey permission. If you do have that permission please update your post with the IAM role your credentials are currently assigned.

There is also a chance that the application default credentials you are using are different than the credentials that you have check the permissions for. I recommend confirming if you using the correct credentials.